# How do I prevent floated-right content from overlapping main content?

Tags: css, overflow, css-float, crop

I have the following HTML:

```
<td class='a'>
  <img src='/images/some_icon.png' alt='Some Icon' />
  <span>Some content that's waaaaaaaaay too long to fit in the allotted space, but which can get cut off.</span>
</td>
```

It should display as follows:

```
[Some content that's wa [ICON]]
```

I have the following CSS:

```
td.a span {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 1;
}

td.a img {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

When I resize the browser to cut off the text, it cuts off at the edge of the `<td>` rather than before the `<img>`, which leaves the `<img>` overlapping the `<span>` content. I've tried various `padding` and `margin`s, but nothing seemed to work. Is this possible?

NB: It's *very* difficult to add a `<td>` that just contains the `<img>` here. If it were easy, I'd just do that :)

Comment: Look at the `clear` directive. I'm not a CSS expert, but putting a float in a `<td>` seems like asking for trouble.

Comment: Float and clear are fine in `<td>` with the exception of Netscape, which messes up when you have float and position: relative in a `<td>`...lord knows why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that `overflow: hidden` isn't working because you are applying it to an inline element.

One solution might be to place that span inside a div, giving that div `overflow: hidden`.  Or change the span to a div.  You may still need to mess around with giving the div a right margin the width of the image.

It would be a lot easier without the `white-space: nowrap` property.  Is there any possible way you could re-design your application so it doesn't need to use this?

Comment: Changing the `<span>` to `display: block` worked perfectly! I also added a little `padding-left` to the image, but that doesn't really have much to do with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
td.a {
   position: relative;
}

td.a span {       
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap; 

   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;

   padding-right: 20px; /* This should be the width of your image */
}

td.a img {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;       
}
```

It will put the image to the far right of your `<td>` and the right padding on the `<span>` will keep the image from overlapping the text.

The reason for the position: relative in the `<td class="a">` is so that it becomes the coordinate system for the position: absolute `<img>`.  You also need a position type (relative, absolute or fixed) for z-index to work.

If that doesn't work, would it be an option to put the image as a background image on the `<span>` like so:

```
td.a span {       
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap; 

   padding-right: 20px; /* This should be the width of your image */
   background: url(your-img.png) no-repeat 100% 0; /* right-top aligned background */
}
```